# Deploying a Meteor app with Distelli

Tags: meteor, deployment, amazon-ec2, devops, meteor-up

I've gotten pretty far into a deployment of my Meteor application on Distelli. Like, almost there. I've done everything as far as setting up the EC2 box, creating a user group [which didn't even seem necessary as I was able to SSH into the box with full rights without specifying my machine's IP], creating an elastic IP, successful build, and deployment to that box. But, I can't seem to check if Meteor is actually running (note: when I ssh in, there are active instances of Mongo and Node, so SOMETHING is running).

The problem has something to do with associating the elastic IP with my ROOT_URL and domain. I'm just not sure what to do at this step and can't seem to find any directions that are Meteor specific. Been using these guides:

https://www.distelli.com/docs/tutorials/how-to-set-up-aws-ec2
https://www.distelli.com/docs/tutorials/deploying-meteor-applications
http://gregblogs.com/tlt-associate-a-namecheap-domain-with-an-amazon-ec2-instance/

Recap: Distelli deployment is a success, but I get the follow error just before finishing:

`Error: $ROOT_URL, if specified, must be an URL`

I've set my ROOT_URL to my domain, and associated according to the previous guide. I can run traceroute on the IP, but like port 3000, so my inclination is the Meteor build is silently failing.

My manifest: https://gist.github.com/newswim/c642bd9a1cf136da73c3

I've noticed that when I point the CNAME record to my ec2 public DNS, NameCheap (aptly named) adds a `.` to the end of the record. Beyond that, I'm pretty much stumped.